# MvvmCross and injecting view model into a view constructor

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross, win-universal-app

Is it possible within MvvmCross to inject a view model into the constructor of a view?

The constructor for my view looks like this:

```
public HomeView(IHomeViewModel viewModel)
{
...
}
```

In the Setup.cs class I manually map view models to views using the following:

```
protected override void InitializeViewLookup()
{
  IDictionary<Type, Type> lookups = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
  {
    {typeof(HomeViewModel), typeof(HomeView)}
  };

  IMvxViewsContainer container = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
  container.AddAll(lookups);
}
```

And in the `Setup.Initialize` method I register `IHomeViewModel` with the IoC container:

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IHomeViewModel, HomeViewModel>();
```

When I run the application the view appears to render, but none of the controls are visible. Plus, if I put a breakpoint inside of the constructor it does not get hit.

So I'm wondering if this is possible or do I need to manually create the view model inside of the view?

P.S. I am creating a Windows Phone Universal application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible within MvvmCross to inject a view model into the constructor of a view?

In the Windows case, it possibly is - if you can work out who constructs the view (it'll be in the Frame somewhere?) and if you can then override it in order to use an IoC container.

However, from a practical point of view, it might be more effort than it's worth.

Instead:

- you could just use the default MvvmCross ViewModel construction/lookup mechanisms - which supply the ViewModel during `OnNavigatedTo` (which then also allows the use of navigation parameters)
- you could invent your own Service Provider lookup - e.g. using `Mvx.Resolve<T>` during the View constructor (or somewhere else)

> So I'm wondering if this is possible or do I need to manually create the view model inside of the view?

From this part of the question, I'm guessing that something is just "going wrong" - but it's hard to know what from the question. To try to debug it you can check the debug trace, you can compare against working sample apps, you can step through the code, etc. If all else fails, drop down to a very simple starter app and try debugging that...

Comment: I think you're right about it being more effort than it's worth when it comes to injecting into the constructor. I wasn't aware that the view model is passed as part of the navigation arguments, but it does solve the problem. Thanks for you help.